# Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 - Outlook - notificationMessages.replaceAsync not working

Tags: outlook, office-js

Since updating to the latest version of Windows Outlook I can no longer see the message created by **Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync**. In a previous version (can't recall which) it was visible:

[image]

In the latest version of Outlook I can see a busy indicator and the text "... Add-in is working on your ... request" but then that disappears but the notification message does not appear.

Edit: This is for **Version 1908 (Build 11929.20254 Click-to-Run)**

[image]

Comment: Could you share the build number you are facing this issue on?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Please see edit.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding notification messages. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, is it a defect? I investigating the same issue until finding this SO question. In my case, the "replaceAsync" call works fine in Outlook web app, but in desktop Outlook application I see the following "[plugin] working on your [request] in [plugin] request"